# For loop error in R on Oracle database tables

Tags: mysql, r, oracle, for-loop, dataframe

Actually I'm facing a problem in executing the for loop in R on Oracle database tables.

The problem is:

I have 4 database tables.

```
**Table Name**->**Columns**

Dim_Customer->Cust_sk_key,Cust_Name,Income,Age

Dim_Product->Product_sk_key,Product_Name

Fact_Sales-> Cust_sk_key,Prdct_sk_key

Market_Basket-> LHS,RHS,sr_key
```

In the final data frame, I need the following columns

```
1.Customer_sk_key
2.Customer_Name
3.income
4.age
5.Product_name
```

While executing without for loop, it is working fine.

```
demo=sqlQuery(con_log, "SELECT  A.CUST_SK_KEY,A.CUST_NM,A.INCOME, A.cust_age, B.PRDCT_NM

FROM IGS_PS_EDW_DIM_CUST A,IGS_PS_EDW_FCT_SALES C, igs_ps_edw_dim_prdct B

WHERE A.cust_sk_key= c.cust_sk_key and 
      b.prdct_sk_key= c.prdct_sk_key and
(**b.prdct_nm ='*Blue Label Canned String Beans*'** or **b.prdct_nm='*Faux Products Buffered Aspirin*'**);")
```

But, while I'm trying to execute the function with a for loop to select LHS,RHS from Market_Basket Table to compare with the b.prdct_nm in the final where condition. I'm getting errors.

```
for(i in 1:11)

{

demo[i] <- sqlQuery(con_ps, paste("SELECT A.CUST_SK_KEY,A.CUST_NM,A.INCOME, A.cust_age, B.PRDCT_NM

 FROM IGS_PS_EDW_DIM_CUST A,IGS_PS_EDW_FCT_SALES C, igs_ps_edw_dim_prdct B

 WHERE A.cust_sk_key= c.cust_sk_key and 
       b.prdct_sk_key= c.prdct_sk_key and
*(b.prdct_nm in (**select LHS from anl_mkt_bskt_anlsys_TEST WHERE SR_KEY=i**) or b.prdct_nm IN (**SELECT RHS FROM anl_mkt_bskt_anlsys_TEST WHERE SR_KEY=i**));"))*


View(demo[i])

}
```

My requirement is: I want to take LHS and RHS from the Market_basket Table from row 1 to nrows and compare it with the b.prdct_nm in the SQL Query.

Please help me with the issue.

Hoping for someone to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

why can't join all 4 tables and having where clause range "WHERE SR_KEYas  >=1 and SR_KEYas  <=11 )

This will faster then , doing in for loop for 10 time.

Comment: Hi , Try it out i had given a clue.  i can't  give the code with out having your environment.

Comment: can you please tell me why the for loop is not iterating while we are using the 'i' value in the select LHS from anl_mkt_bskt_anlsys_TEST WHERE SR_KEY=i .